# Rails 4.2.3 ActiveRecord Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, jruby

All:

I am working on a project using the Ruby-on-Rails Framework. This project was initially based on Rails 4.0.9. I did a Brakeman Vulnerability Scan and I got n "Medium" level issue report that 4.0.9 is prone to DoS attack so I upgraded to 4.2.3.

But after the upgrade, I first got an error about "*tzinfo*" Data Source not found so I included the *tzinfo-data* gem with the platforms specification. That done, then my DB Queries using ActiveRecord Model starts failing whenever I do a method call on the results from the query.

**CODE:**

```
query = ['SELECT id, firstname, lastname, status, code FROM giftcard_orders WHERE phone = ? AND description LIKE ? ', phone, '%'+search]

@users = User.find_by_sql(query)

if @users.count > 0
   @users.each do |user|
       user[:code] = user[:code].do_decrypt
   end
end
```

But immediately after the find_by_sql, I get some errors as below:

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 685ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

*

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `type' for "int identity(10)":String):
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:64:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:53:in `inherited'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:61:in `matching'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2468:in `select'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:60:in `matching'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:56:in `decorators_for'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:47:in `apply'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:29:in `add_user_provided_columns'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2399:in `collect'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2412:in `map'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:28:in `add_user_provided_columns'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attributes.rb:98:in `columns_hash'
  C:0:in `columns_hash'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1067:in `arel_columns'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2399:in `collect'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2412:in `map'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1066:in `arel_columns'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1059:in `build_select'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:878:in `build_arel'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:858:in `arel'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:210:in `perform_calculation'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:127:in `calculate'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:42:in `count'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:268:in `empty?'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:278:in `any?'
```

*

Comment: is `type` a attribute ?

Comment: No. type is a method called in the Rails Framework.

Comment: Did you try to create '%'+search before this call?   search = "%#{search}"

Answer (score 0):

The method `ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql` has been deprecated for this Rails version: 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

You should use `ActiveRecord::Querying.find_by_sql` as an alternative.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql

### UPDATE

I am not really sure about your error, but I recommend you to:

1. See what happens with a simple query example, like `select id FROM giftcard_orders`,
2. Use directly the module:

   `ActiveRecord::Querying.find_by_sql(['select id FROM giftcard_orders'])`
3. If this doesn't work, try to check that the find_by_sql method is called. Be careful with this:

   `$> bundle open activerecord` go to `lib/activerecord/querying.rb` and put something to show you that is really using it (maybe a rails logger or a pry)
   https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb
4. If you suspect is an ActiveRecord bug, open an issue on the github Rails repository:

   https://github.com/rails/rails/issues

Comment: Can you give an example relative to the User model?

Comment: The two looks the same on the documentation page. Could you provide me an example of the ActiveRecord::Querying.find_by_sql?

Comment: I have add you some comments.